# set logging level com.openhtmlpdf to ERROR only

Tags: java, logging, openhtmltopdf

So I use openhtmltopdf library to render my HTML to pdf, every time it run it will show info log like below. Is there any way to set the logging level to only ERROR/SEVERE only

```
public File exportToPdfBox(Map<String, Object> variables, String templatePath, String out) {
    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(out);) {
        // There are more options on the builder than shown below.
        PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
        builder.withHtmlContent(getHtmlString(variables, templatePath), "file:");
        builder.toStream(os);
        builder.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception while generating pdf : {}", e);
    }
    return new File(out);
}
```

My stack trace

```
com.openhtmltopdf.load INFO:: SAX XMLReader in use (parser):com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser
 com.openhtmltopdf.load INFO:: SAX XMLReader in use (parser):
 com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser
 com.openhtmltopdf.load INFO:: Loaded document in ~43ms
 com.openhtmltopdf.load INFO:: TIME: parse stylesheets  200ms
 com.openhtmltopdf.match INFO:: media = print com.openhtmltopdf.match
 INFO:: Matcher created with 1180 selector
```

s

i try `XRLog.setLevel()` but it seems to not working, right now i only know `XRLog.setLoggingEnabled`can turn off the log but I don't want to turn it off. I only want the **ERROR** log to show not the info. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in v1.0.4.

```
XRLog.listRegisteredLoggers().forEach(logger -> XRLog.setLevel(logger, java.util.logging.Level.OFF));
```

Details here: https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/wiki/Logging

Comment: Where did you add this? Can you do it globally for the entire app? Or do you have to do it everywhere that you call the Pdf classes?